# How to pass class as parameter to Jsoniter-Scala codec maker?

Tags: json, scala

I am using jsoniter-scala to map Json files to Scala objects (case classes). To make it simple, assume I have two types of Json files, and thus two case classes, for instance:

```
case class JsonTypeOne(name: String, id: Long)
case class JsonTypeTwo(name: String, notes: Seq[String])
```

When I use

```
val codec: JsonValueCodec[JsonTypeOne] = JsonCodecMaker.make
```

or

```
val codec: JsonValueCodec[JsonTypeTwo] = JsonCodecMaker.make
```

everything works perfectly and as expected. Now, I'd like to create a function that takes the class as an in input parameter and passes it on to jsoniter. In pseudo-code this would be something like this:

```
def getJsonWithClass(aClass: SomeType, jsonString: String) {
   val codec: JsonValueCodec[aClass] = JsonCodecMaker.make
   readFromString(jsonString)(codec)
}
```

and would then be called as follows:

```
getJsonWithClass(JsonTypeOne, json1String)
getJsonWithClass(JsonTypeTwo, json2String)
```

Tried a number of variations, including defining a trait for the case classes and using that as "SomeType" or using generics, but thus far without success.

Any suggestions on how to resolve this issue would be highly appreciated.

Comment: You want to pass a type, not a class. Also, you do not want to derive the codec for each invocation. - Do this: `def getJsonWithClass[T : JsonValueCodec](jsonString: String): T = readFromString(jsonString)` And put this line in the companion object of each case class: `implicit val codec: JsonValueCodec[JsonTypeOne] = JsonCodecMaker.make` finally call the function like: `getJsonWithClass[JsonTypeOne](json1String)` but at this point, your function is just a useless wrapper over just calling: `readFromString[JsonTypeOne](json1String)`

Comment: I thought about something similar as well, but that requires that every case class (JsonTypeOne / ... Two) needs to be are aware of the underlying Json parsing approach, i.e. jsoniter and the codec creation, which is something I want to avoid (separation of concerns). In the real system, the function is part of a class that's instantiated once for every type of Json file and the codec is only derived once. The function call was just for purposes of testing the passing of the class / type as parameter.

Comment: You may instead of pass the codec pass what the `JsonCodecMaker.make` expects which is probably and `HList` and a bunch of other things which will make your code even more coupled than just deriving the code for the case class in its companion object. - Another approach, is to derive the codecs, not in the companion objects but where they are used. So, before calling `readFromString[JsonTypeOne]`  you will do `implicit val codecJsonValueCodec[JsonTypeOne] = JsonCodecMaker.make`

Comment: Indeed, I try to derive the codecs where they are used, but would like to use dynamic insteading of static typing, i.e. replace the static "JsonTypeOne" with a dynamic variable taking either JsonTypeOne or JsonTypeTwo (or other suitable case classes) as a type parameter. And that's what I'm struggling to achieve

Comment: You can't, that is the point. `JsonCodecMaker.make` doesn't just magically derive it. It needs to know the concrete type to derive the codec either using **Shapeless** or a macro. So you need to either ask for the codec and move the generation of the codec to whoever call that method.

Comment: @peter-k `JsonCodecMaker.make` derives codecs in the compile time only for security and performance reasons.

Could you please explain why do you need such function? Probably the root problem can be solved in a different way.

Comment: Now I get it. Have been looking at it the wrong way. @AndriyPlokhotnyuk : As I need to create a service which can parse in parallel a stream of Json files with a dozen different, but fixed structures I wanted to create  a "common" parsing core parameterized with the structures.

Answer (score 2):

As it is not possible to parameterize the codec generation as originally intended (thanks for the clarifications Luis and Andriy), I ended up with a workaround. It's not as cleanly decoupled as if parameterized typing would be possible, but at least the coupling is localized in a pattern matching and can easily be extended:

```
def getJsonWithClass[T](aJsonClass: T, jsonString: String):T = {
  val jsonCodec = aJsonClass match {
      case JsonTypeOne => JsonCodecMaker.make[JsonTypeOne]
      case JsonTypeTwo => JsonCodecMaker.make[JsonTypeTwo]
  }

  val jsonObj = readFromString(jsonString)(jsonCodec)
  jsonObj.asInstanceOf[T]
}
```

This can then be called as in

```
getJsonWithClass(JsonTypeOne, aJsonTypeOneString)
```